# Система лута Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Возникла необходимость сделать систему выпадения лута, причем шанс выпадения вещи должен быть привязан к монстру, а не быть значением поля вещи.

Раньше как то попадалось решение, но сейчас найти не могу, там как то можно было указать размерность массива лут листа в монстре и в каждом элементе массива было 2 поля - один это ссылка на префаб, а второе числовое значение.

Может быть кто то подскажет как подобную схему можно реализовать?

Есть лист выпадения предметов из монстра, нужно как то указать шансы выпадения каждой вещи, шансы для каждой вещи у двух разных типов монтсров могут отличаться.

Сейчас у меня так:

Проблема в том,  что тут шанс берется из вещи,  а необходимо из монстра.  Как то можно создать лист парных значений ссылка на префаб,  шанс в скрипте монстра?

```
public double[] VerGenerator(GameObject[] lootList)
{
    double[] ver = new double[lootList.Length];
    ver[0] = lootList[0].gameObject.GetComponent<Item>().ver / 100d;
    for (int i = 1; i < lootList.Length; i++)
    {
        ver[i] = lootList[i].gameObject.GetComponent<Item>().ver/100d+ (ver[i - 1]);
    }
    return ver;
    
}

public int LootGenerator(GameObject[] lootList)
{
    int result = 0;
    double rand = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
    double[] ver = VerGenerator(lootList);
    for (int j = 0; j < ver.Length; j++)
    {
        if (ver[j] >= rand)
        {
            result = j;
            return j;
        }
        else
        {
            result = -1;
        }
            
    }
    return result;  
       
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46858/discussion-on-question-by-phpred---unity3d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался - в скрипте монстра создал класс Loot с двумя public полями

```
[System.Serializable]
    public class Loot
    {
        public GameObject lootPrefab;
        public int chance;
    }
```

в самом классе монстра создал массив классов loot.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть лист выпадения предметов из монстра, нужно как то указать шансы выпадения каждой вещи, шансы для каждой вещи у двух разных типов монтсров могут отличаться.

Можно использовать множество, с парами "ссылка на лут(префаб)" - "вероятность выпадения(число)"

1. Суммируем все вероятности из множества.
2. Берем рандом от 0 до этой суммы.
3. Узнаем какому элементу принадлежит рандом.

Пример:

в списке вероятности "x" - "25", "y" - "25", "z" - "50".

Сумма = 100.

Рандом пусть = 56.

Значит берем лут под именем "z". Потому что вероятность выпадения x(0,25](1/4),       y(25,50](1/4),   z(50,100](1/2).

Префаб загрузить можно так:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

ПС: математику я всегда прогуливал, так что сами проверяйте.

Comment: @ Алексей Шиманский чего? Если число выпадет между 25 и 50 то берем "y", от 0 до 25 берем "x"

Comment: просто по началу кажется что не интервал между, а десятичные дроби

Comment: не, с самим вычислением предмета я более менее разобрался и алгоритмом выборки, я делаю примерно так:

Comment: В шапке, не совсем еще разобрался как пользоваться сервисом(

Comment: Для меня сейчас проблема именно в том, что шанс берется из компонента Item, он висит на префабе итема. Но мне необходимо чтоб к примеру с гоблина дерево падало с шансом 5%, а к примеру с орка то же самое дерево с шансом 3%(пример образный), тоесть задавать вероятность в префабе для меня не подходит, а вот как ее задать в каждом конкретном монстре и привязать к итемам при этом никак не пойму...

Comment: @phpred в скрипте каждого монстра должен быть свой список("предмет"-"вероятность"). К тому же твой алгоритм не верный, потому что некоторые предметы, может так случится, никогда не выпадут. А мой алгоритм не учитывает что ничего не может выпасть(хотя для "ничего" тоже можно задать вероятность).

Comment: скрипте каждого монстра должен быть свой список("предмет"-"вероятность") - вот именно это я и ищу. Можно поподробнее рассказать как это реализуется? Недавно просто изучаю C#. И по поводу скрипта - как может получиться что какие то предметы никогда не выпадут? Я хотел добиться варианта чтоб иногда ничего не выпадало, поэтому делил на 100, а не на сумму элементов массива.

Comment: Точно, можно же создать класс  с public полями Item, chance и в монстре создавать уже массив этих классов. Спасибо.

Comment: хотя нет, что то я намудрил)