# Система рандомного лута в сундуке (Unity3D, C#)

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, случайные-числа

Нужна помощь. Я хочу сделать систему рандомного лута из сундука для игры, но не получается. К примеру есть 5 категории: Обычные, Рарная, Мистическая, Эпическая, Легендарная.
Шанс, что может выпасть Обычная 65%, Рарная 45%, Мистическая 25%, Эпическая 15%, а Легендарная 5%. Например в будущем Категории предметов могут увеличиться, а шансы поменяться.
У меня была идея, к каждому предмету привязать свою цифру, и сделать массив, ну и тут столкнулся с проблемой, я новичок с Unity3D, и знания по C# не много забыты.
Будет несколько сундуков, с ячейками лута. Например обычный сундук имеет 10 ячеек, и в этом сундуке может выпасть 10 рандомных предмета.
Помогите пожалуйста, как вот такое дело можно оформить в виде кода.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: 65+45+25+15+5=155%. Что означают лишние 55%? :)

Comment: уже было что-то подобное http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/578537/191482

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд самое простое, может быть и не самое правильное, решение - это взять и генерировать числа от 1 до 155, а далее смотреть, если число в промежутке:

- от 1 до 65 - `Обычная`
- от 66 до 110 - `Рарная`
- от 111 до 135 - `Мистическая`
- от 136 до 150 - `Эпическая`
- от 151 до 155 - `Легендарная`

Естественно последовательность чисел можно менять и, например, для `Легендарной` сравнивать с числами вроде `33, 111, 145, 1, 7`. Для остальных задать свои числа

Что сказать про:

> Например в будущем Категории предметов могут увеличиться, а шансы поменяться.

Создайте класс `Category` в нем должно быть свойство `Chance`(Шанс), далее берем все категории и суммируем "шансы", получаем верхний порог генерации чисел

Для

> Например обычный сундук имеет 10 ячеек, и в этом сундуке может выпасть
>   10 рандомных предмета.

можно в цикле для каждой ячейки вызывать код, который будет возвращать предмет

**UPD**

```
class Category {
    private int[] chanceValues;

    public Category(string name, int chance){
        Name = name;
        Chance = chance;
        chanceValues = generateChanceValues(chance);
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Chance { get; private set; }

    private int[] generateChanceValues(int count){
        int[] res = new int[count];
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; count++){
            res[i] = random.Next(1, 101);
        }

        return res;
    }

    public bool IsGenerateLoot(int number){
        if (chanceValues == null)
            return false;
        return chanceValues.Contains(number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм, идея не плохая, только для меня теперь остается проблемой приравнять объект к цифре. А потом я кое-как попробую сделать массив, чтобы от 1 до 155 Генировал случайное число.

Comment: @Dipper я вас не понимаю. Что значит приравнять объект к цифре?

Comment: Я запутался. Идея была в том чтобы был рандом, и выдает любые 10 цифр. И потом идет проверка если цифра 59 = Key тогда этот предмет спауниться.

Comment: Тот факт, что "шансы" ТС не суммируются в 100%, очевидно, говорит о том, что вещи разных категорий выпадают независимо, т.е. несколько вещей может выпадать одновременно. А предложенный вами способ подразумевает взаимоисключающее выпадение вещей.

Comment: @AnT Вы хотите сказать, что есть вариант, когда могут выпадать сразу все вещи? Тогда генерация от 1 до 100 и проверяем каждую категорию на вхождение

Comment: @Vadim Prokopchuk: Это уже у ТС надо спрашивать. Но сам факт того, что шансы не суммируются в 100% уже наводит на вопросы. Что имеется в виду?

Comment: Да, шансы не равны 100%, потому-что, несколько вещей может выпать одновременно.

Comment: @Dipper Вам это оформить в виде кода?

Comment: Да, пожалуйста, заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Dipper обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо большое, если нужна будет помощь, можно будет к вам обратиться ?

Comment: Ошибка, пытаюсь фиксить. - random не содержит определения для next и не удалось найти метод расширения Next

Comment: У меня появилась вот такая идея,  а может сделать как бы базу предметов, с категориями, а рандом бы выбирал из этой базы, предметы с шансами.
Для Юнити мы добавляем 'public GameObject priver1', чтобы создать предмет используем команду 'Instantiate(priver1)' в конце рандома.

Comment: @Dipper поправил Next(100). Про базу - как вашей душе угодно)

Comment: Ошибка осталась :D

Comment: Все равно остается, ладно сам исправлю, спасибо.