# Рандомизация по шансам

Tags: unity3d, случайные-числа

Здравствуйте товарищи программисты!

Интересует такой вопрос, может кто то уже решал, или есть идея.

Все знаем что в юини 2 функции рандома, net и самого юнити Random.Range

Задача:
Допустим есть 5 префабов (для генерации) и у каждого префаба шанс выпадения (допустим берем от общего числа 100%).

Пример:
Вилка 50%
Ложка 20%
Кружка 20%
Тарелка 10%

Вопрос:
Как лучше реализовать рандом именно по процентам?

Сделать рандом.ранже(1,100) и проверять в какой диапазон попало?

Или другой вариант. Каждый вариант рандома допустим тарелка 10% проверять на Рандом.Ранже(1,100) и если она сюда попала значит спавнить её

Comment: и второй http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/578550/191482

Comment: Во втором варианте события спавна становятся зависимыми - вероятности будут не те.

Comment: спасибо, через поиск находил только про числа

Comment: я думаю вариант первый с редкостью Обычная, Рарная и т.д лучший вариант, тем более можно сразу ввести редкость и использовать для всех объектов которые будут в рандоме

Comment: Хотя это наверное не слишком подходит. Если будет например 3 объекта с 10% каждый, то тут поставив редкость Обычная у них одинаковый диапазон будет числ?